# Split delimited string using variable substitution

Tags: text-processing, ksh

I have a sample file the lines of which are delimited by "#" and it contains 3 fields.

```
A#B#C
D#E#F
```

Can I use UNIX variable substitution instead of the following to get values of each field in the lines?

```
cat file | while read a; do
    f1=`echo $a | cut -d# -f1`
    f2=`echo $a | cut -d# -f2`
    f3=`echo $a | cut -d# -f3`
 done
```

Comment: Your example command overwrites the variables f1,2,3 with always the last line of your input. Not sure what you want to do with the variables then ...

Comment: I will be using f1,2,3 in values for each loop iteration, so the last value is expected to be values of the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion if that's what you mean. But it's not very readable:

```
while read a; do
  # comments are for the first line A#B#C
  f1f2=${a%#*}  # remove suffix #C -> A#B
  f1=${f1f2%#*} # remove suffix #B -> A
  f2=${f1f2#*#} # remove prefix A# -> B
  f3=${a##*#}   # remove longest prefix: A#B# -> C
  echo "$f1,$f2,$f3" # do something with f1,f2,f3
done < file
```

It's easier to set the internal field separator variable to `IFS=#` and split each line into three variables:

```
while IFS=# read f1 f2 f3; do
  echo "$f1,$f2,$f3" # do something with f1,f2,f3
done < file
```

Comment: @ Freddy: checked the while loop, works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In ksh, you can also use arrays:

```
while IFS='#' read -A arr; do
    echo "${#arr[@]} items, second item: ${arr[1]}"
done < file
```

`read -A` works in Zsh too, but the array indexes are one-based. Bash's `read -a` works similarly to the ksh one.